# Splitting xml tag in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to split the below xml tag using the split function in python

```
<Item Name="Caption" Type="String">Python</Item>
```

The split function I have used:

```
output = data.split("<Item Name=Title Type=String>")[1].split("</Item>")[0]
```

Comment: You haven't included the XML you wish to split. Please edit your post.

Comment: Why aren't you using an [xml parser](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)?

Comment: <Item Name="Caption" Type="String">Python</Item>
 This is the XML line that I need to split

Answer (score 0):

For that simple tag, you can do this:

```
def get_xml_tag_content(tag: str) -> str:
    return tag.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]


tag = '<Item Name="Caption" Type="String">Python</Item>'
tag_content = get_xml_tag_content(tag)

print(tag_content)  # Python
```

At first, we split our tag by **the closing `>` of the opening tag**, we take the second element of the result, which is `Python</Item>`, and then we split it by **the opening < of the closing tag** and take the first element, which is exactly the tag's content. (`Python`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split the XML tag to get the info you want, Python has [xml parsers](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) that does this for you

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring

data = '<Item Name="Caption" Type="String">Python</Item>'
e = fromstring(data)

print('Text: ', e.text)
print('Tag:  ', e.tag)
print('Name: ', e.attrib['Name'])
print('Type: ', e.attrib['Type'])

>>> Text:  Python
>>> Tag:   Item
>>> Name:  Caption
>>> Type:  String
```

Comment: I only need to extract the word "Python" from the tag that is why I am splitting .Kindly suggest